# How to make pop-up window appear in the divided portion of the frame

Tags: window, frames

When using the `popwin` mode, I notice that the pop-up window always appears at the bottom of the entire frame. For example, given the frame contains two windows, divided vertically, and I am editing the left one

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+            |            +   
+  Editting  |            +   
+   window   |            +   
+            |            +   
+            |            +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

When performing some task, for example, compiling the editting file, the pop-up window in `popwin` mode will appear as follow:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  Editting  |            +   
+   window   |            +   
+            |            +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+         pop-win         +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I find out that it's is a waste of space that the pop-up window occupies and the other window is shrunk, consequently.

So, I would like to ask if `popwin` mode can be configured to appear as follow?

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  Editting  |            +   
+   window   |            +   
+            |            +   
++++++++++++++            +
+   pop-win  |            +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Thank you very much for spending your time to read my question. Any helps is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popwin doesn't have a customizable way to achieve what you ask for, but we can hack it by overriding the function `popwin:popup-buffer`. Essentially, we replace the call to `popwin:create-popup-window` with code that displays the popup buffer in a new split:

```lisp
(let* ((orig-window (selected-window))
      (new-window (split-window orig-window nil 'below)))
  (set-window-buffer new-window buffer)
  (list orig-window new-window nil))
```

This piece of code returns a "master window", which is the original window, a "popup window", which is the window used for the popup buffer, and a "window map", which is nil. In the original version, `popwin:create-popup-window` calls `popwin:replicate-window-config` and returns the result as the "window map". In turn, `popwin:replicate-window-config` returns nil if the frame has more than one window (maybe a bug), otherwise it returns some other value.

This answer is more a proof-of-concept than a polished solution, but of course you can improve on it if you find it necessary.

```lisp
(defun* popwin:popup-buffer (buffer
                            &key
                            (width popwin:popup-window-width)
                            (height popwin:popup-window-height)
                            (position popwin:popup-window-position)
                            noselect
                            dedicated
                            stick
                            tail)
  "Show BUFFER in a popup window and return the popup window. If
NOSELECT is non-nil, the popup window will not be selected. If
STICK is non-nil, the popup window will be stuck. If TAIL is
non-nil, the popup window will show the last contents. Calling
`popwin:popup-buffer' during `popwin:popup-buffer' is allowed. In
that case, the buffer of the popup window will be replaced with
BUFFER."
  (interactive "BPopup buffer:\n")
  (setq buffer (get-buffer buffer))
  (popwin:push-context)
  (run-hooks 'popwin:before-popup-hook)
  (multiple-value-bind (context context-stack)
      (popwin:find-context-for-buffer buffer :valid-only t)
    (if context
        (progn
          (popwin:use-context context)
          (setq popwin:context-stack context-stack))
      (let ((win-outline (car (popwin:window-config-tree))))
        (destructuring-bind (master-win popup-win win-map)
            (let ((size (if (popwin:position-horizontal-p position) width height))
                  (adjust popwin:adjust-other-windows))
              ;; (popwin:create-popup-window size position adjust)       ; <-- original line
              (let* ((orig-window (selected-window))                     ; <-- modifications
                    (new-window (split-window orig-window nil 'below)))  ; <--
                (set-window-buffer new-window buffer)                    ; <--
                (list orig-window new-window nil))                       ; <--
              )
          (setq popwin:popup-window popup-win
                popwin:master-window master-win
                popwin:window-outline win-outline
                popwin:window-map win-map
                popwin:window-config nil
                popwin:selected-window (selected-window)))
        (popwin:update-window-reference 'popwin:context-stack :recursive t)
        (popwin:start-close-popup-window-timer))
      (with-selected-window popwin:popup-window
        (popwin:switch-to-buffer buffer)
        (when tail
          (set-window-point popwin:popup-window (point-max))
          (recenter -2)))
      (setq popwin:popup-buffer buffer
            popwin:popup-last-config (list buffer
                                          :width width :height height :position position
                                          :noselect noselect :dedicated dedicated
                                          :stick stick :tail tail)
            popwin:popup-window-dedicated-p dedicated
            popwin:popup-window-stuck-p stick)))
  (if noselect
      (setq popwin:focus-window popwin:selected-window)
    (setq popwin:focus-window popwin:popup-window)
    (select-window popwin:popup-window))
  (run-hooks 'popwin:after-popup-hook)
  popwin:popup-window)
```

Comment: It's so nice that you gave a so detailed answer. It's even so wonderful that your answer works nicely! Thank you very much! This is definitely an awesome feature that `popwin` lacks, in my opinion.

Comment: I make a small modification to adjust the popup-window-height according to the customization of `popwin` mode:
              (let* ((popup-win-height (- popwin:popup-window-height))
                     (orig-window (selected-window))
                     (new-window (split-window orig-window popup-win-height 'below)))
                (set-window-buffer new-window buffer)
                (list orig-window new-window nil))

Comment: Sorry, the code inserted in my comment above is kind of ugly since all of the new-line characters are trimmed